# Maximum distance for intramolecular proton transfer

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

In this reaction (formation of ester from ketone / aldehyde), intramolecular proton transfer happens, since it can stabilize the formal positive charge by resonance after that. This transfer happens across 3 atoms. ($\ce{O-O-C}$)

[image]
However, in this step (formation of acetal from $\ce{C=O}$) using alcohol, the book says it does not occur, since the $\ce{O}$ and $\ce{H}$ are 'too far' apart. This 'transfer' happens only across 2 atoms ($\ce{C-O}$). Which is less than the above reaction ($\ce{O-O-C}$). If that can occur, why can't the proton transfer here not occur?

What is the **real** factor that determines whether an intramolecular proton transfer can happen?

Comment: (1) What book is this? (2) Consider looking into Baldwin's rules. FWIW I would be inclined to draw the first one as two separate steps.

Comment: Electrons transfer occours through (usually double) bonds, *protons* transfer through *space*.

Comment: @orthocresol 'organic chemistry as a second language', I am struggling to figure out Baldwin's rules. It seems to apply in a ring formation (I don't know whether I am correct), is this applicable to the explanation for the second one? Thanks

Comment: @Karl sorry if I am not mistaken, if any protons can transfer through space, this means actually the transfer in the second one is workable?

Comment: What do you mean by "any"? I only said that if there is a viable (especially *short enough*) trajectory, a proton does not care from what (part of a) molecule it comes.  *If* the reaction happens of course depends on a lot of additional factors.

Comment: @Karl sorry for mistaking, can I say the first one is able to do the transfer since the atoms are somehow 'coiled up' (from the figure), thus reducing the distance between O and H. And the second one is unable due to electric repulsion of 2 O atoms in the vicinity, thus increase the separation (not short enough)?